# Automate columns merging where merged values are separated with a delimiter in the container

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a big dataframe where a lot of columns's column names have `.` in their names. Here is my approach in the example below:

```r
#this somewhat resembles what we have in hand
df <- data.frame(id= c("HD1", "HD2", "HD3", "HD4"),
                 mon.1= c(1, 0, 1, 4),
                 mon.2= c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 mon.2.4.1...1= c("#ji", "#ki", NA, "#ui"),
                 tue.6= c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                 tue= c(190, 2345, 41, 89),
                 heh= c("1mn", "2a", "g78", "asd324"),
                 wed= c(1890, 9002, 14341, 657),
                 wed.01= c(NA, "@ksdf", NA, NA),
                 thu.0234= c("@jksdff", "@sfd", "@kukg.676", "@jdkfjk"),
                 rating= c(1,2,3,4))

#in order to collapse the columns, we can apply a mapply variant

#here i attach a new column to original df named combined1 which collapses all mon.....
df<- within(df, 
       combined1 <- Map(list, as.character(mon.1),
                        as.character(mon.2),
                        as.character(mon.2.4.1...1)))

#process repeats for others
df <- within(df,
         combined2 <- Map(list, as.character(tue.6),
                        as.character(tue)))

df <- within(df,
        combined3 <- Map(list, as.character(wed),
                        as.character(wed.01)))
```

Yields a comma delimintaed columns `Combined1`, `Combined2`,`Combined3` :

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 14
  id    mon.1 mon.2 mon.2.4.1...1 tue.6   tue heh     wed wed.01 thu.0234 rating
  <fct> <dbl> <fct> <fct>         <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>  <fct>     <dbl>
1 HD1       1 a     #ji           1       190 1mn    1890 NA     @jksdff       1
2 HD2       0 b     #ki           2      2345 2a     9002 @ksdf  @sfd          2
3 HD3       1 c     NA            3        41 g78   14341 NA     @kukg.6~      3
4 HD4       4 d     #ui           4        89 asd3~   657 NA     @jdkfjk       4
# ... with 3 more variables: combined1 <named list>, combined2 <named list>,
#   combined3 <named list>
```

My problem is that there are about 20-30 columns for `mon`, `tue` and `wed` and I am having issue creating a method where it will read all for eg, `wed`, `wed1.43654`, `wed.46` and so on. Then I don't have to manually type them in. Will appreciate your help!

**EDIT**
Something like this

```r
> df[,11:14]
  rating combined1 combined2   combined3
1      1 1, a, #ji    1, 190    1890, NA
2      2 0, b, #ki   2, 2345 9002, @ksdf
3      3  1, c, NA     3, 41   14341, NA
4      4 4, d, #ui     4, 89     657, NA
```

Comment: What is your expected output.  Do you want to simply create a `list` column?

Comment: Hi @akrun, expected output be something like above (a vector of values is also good), but where I don't have to manually insert all `wed`, `wed.01` columns. I wanted to see if I can automate that. Like I say ok let's merge all the column starting with `wed` together. Do you understand? Sorry english is not good for me.

Comment: That is easier, there are some columns like 'heh', i guess not to be considered?

Comment: @akrun, yeah there columns that are Ok as is if they are unique or they exist independently. Only some columns in my csv have this problem where a lot of columns are redundant because they were just given a new name after `.`

Comment: Please check my solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option where we remove the suffix part of the column names starting with `.` ('nm1'), create a frequency `table`, extract those names having more than one count ('nm2'), loop over those unique names, extract the columns from the dataset with `grep`, and assign it to create 'combined' columns

```
nm1 <- sub("\\..*", "", names(df))
nm2 <- names(which(table(nm1) > 1))
df[paste0('combined', seq_along(nm2))] <- lapply(nm2, 
        function(x) df[grep(x, names(df))])



df$combined1
#  mon.1 mon.2 mon.2.4.1...1
#1     1     a           #ji
#2     0     b           #ki
#3     1     c          <NA>
#4     4     d           #ui
```

---

If we want this to be a `list` column

```
df[paste0('combined', seq_along(nm2))] <- lapply(nm2, 
        function(x) 
        apply(df[grep(x, names(df))], 1, function(x) as.list(c(x))))


df
#   id mon.1 mon.2 mon.2.4.1...1 tue.6  tue    heh   wed wed.01  thu.0234 rating combined1 combined2    combined3
#1 HD1     1     a           #ji     1  190    1mn  1890   <NA>   @jksdff      1 1, a, #ji   1,  190     1890, NA
#2 HD2     0     b           #ki     2 2345     2a  9002  @ksdf      @sfd      2 0, b, #ki   2, 2345  9002, @ksdf
#3 HD3     1     c          <NA>     3   41    g78 14341   <NA> @kukg.676      3  1, c, NA   3,   41    14341, NA
#4 HD4     4     d           #ui     4   89 asd324   657   <NA>   @jdkfjk      4 4, d, #ui   4,   89      657, NA
```

Comment: Thank you akrun brother. I think I got you lost in translation somewhere. Currently I got new columns, what I wanted is have all ie, `mon` columns combined into one. Like row in  `combined1` for mon look like `c(1, "a", "#ji"). EDIT. Let me show you output above

Comment: @WolfgangBagdanow if you check the `str(df)`, the 'combined1', 'combined2', 'combined3' etc are 'data.frame' columns.  If you need only `list` then it can be done

Comment: Yeah please, It would be nice if can have them in a list form or something because I will writing them to a file. My goal is to cut-down unnecessary column creations. I put down how I would like in my question above

Comment: @WolfgangBagdanow in your `Map` based solution, it is converting each element to character.  Do you want this to remain as the same type or different type because `mon.1` is not character

Comment: Once they're in a container, it would be preffered to have them as character, because I can convert them later to their appropriate forms. What do you think brother? you have more experience than I do.

Comment: @WolfgangBagdanow i updated the post.  If you are sure that similar columns should be of the same type, that seems logical

Comment: Gotcha brother. Yes they're are similar type I just put out an extreme scenario case heheeh. Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate your help as always!

Answer (score 2):

WolfgangBagdanow-

> Yeah please, It would be nice if can have them in a list form or
>   something because I will writing them to a file. My goal is to
>   cut-down unnecessary column creations. I put down how I would like in
>   my question above

This is sort of extension on @akrun's second answer. If you do decide to write this `df` to a csv file then know that neither `readr`, `data.table` nor `base` write csv method will work because they don't have method implemented yet that write a list to a csv file (as far as I know). In order to write your dataframe which will have a list columns to a csv file you would need something like this-

```r
#@akrun 's list method-
#df <- data.frame(...)

df[paste0('combined', seq_along(nm2))] <- lapply(nm2, 
        function(x) 
        apply(df[grep(x, names(df))], 1, function(x) as.list(c(x))))

#------------------------------------
set_lists_to_chars <- function(x) {
  if(class(x) == 'list') {
    y <- paste(unlist(x[1]), sep='', collapse=', ')
  } else {
    y <- x 
  }
  return(y)
}
new_frame <- data.frame(lapply(tibble(df), set_lists_to_chars), stringsAsFactors = F)
write.csv(new_frame, file='test.csv')
```

Alternatively, you can also convert your list to char using `apply` method. Anyways, this would get you what want in csv. Hopefully. Nice question by the way, paired with an excellent answer given by @akrun. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @ultapitt brother, I just used `df <- apply(df,2,as.character)` but thank you for your input too. Take care!

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're trying to prep for csv a common dodge is using pipes to separate so full credit to @akrun for the hard part but...

```r
nm1 <- sub("\\..*", "", names(df))
nm2 <- names(which(table(nm1) > 1))

df[paste0('combined', seq_along(nm2))] <- lapply(nm2, 
                                                 function(x) 
                                                   apply(df[grep(x, names(df))], 
                                                         1, 
                                                         function(x) str_replace_all(toString(x), 
                                                                                     pattern = ", ", 
                                                                                     replacement = "|")))

> df
   id mon.1 mon.2 mon.2.4.1...1 tue.6  tue    heh   wed wed.01  thu.0234 rating combined1 combined2   combined3
1 HD1     1     a           #ji     1  190    1mn  1890   <NA>   @jksdff      1   1|a|#ji    1| 190     1890|NA
2 HD2     0     b           #ki     2 2345     2a  9002  @ksdf      @sfd      2   0|b|#ki    2|2345  9002|@ksdf
3 HD3     1     c          <NA>     3   41    g78 14341   <NA> @kukg.676      3    1|c|NA    3|  41    14341|NA
4 HD4     4     d           #ui     4   89 asd324   657   <NA>   @jdkfjk      4   4|d|#ui    4|  89      657|NA
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this. Thank you for sharing Chuck P! Take care sir :)